# VB.Net - Bind a TextBox to a collection's property

Tags: vb.net, collections, binding

I have an Account class and Accountlist collection.

```
Public ReadOnly Property TotalAmount() As Decimal
    Get
        If ACCOUNTList.Count > 0 Then
            Return ACCOUNTList.Sum(Function(s) s.InvoiceAmount)
        Else
            Return 0
        End If            
    End Get
End Property
```

As it can be seen in code above I like to bind TotalAmount property which is in Accountlist collection to a textBox so that when BindingSource changes the textBox's value changes automatically. I can access collection Count in BindingSource but I have no idea how I can bind TotalAmount property to the BindingSource! How can I achieve this?

```
 Private Sub ACCOUNTBindingSource_ListChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs) Handles ACCOUNTBindingSource.ListChanged
        txtBox1.Text = ACCOUNTBindingSource.Count
        txtBox2.Text = ACCOUNTBindingSource.???

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it to a Function () as :

```
Public Function TotalAmount() As Decimal
    If ACCOUNTList.Count > 0 Then
        Return ACCOUNTList.Sum(Function(s) s.InvoiceAmount)
    Else
        Return 0
    End If            
End Function
```

So every time you use Textbox1.Text = [Some Class].TotalAmount().ToString() it processes and returns new summaried value

Comment: I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error when User control load for first time cause ACCOUNTBindingSource.Count=0

Comment: OK, it seems you have a dynamic class (not static). Try to create an instance of [YourClass]. In this case it will : Textbox1.Text = new [Some Class].TotalAmount().ToString()

Answer (score 1):

Your class will need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you just need to call the PropertyChanged event. There also a good little example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx).